# Can I init an Angular ngModel in html, and then use its value in controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<form>
<!-- one way to do it -->
<input ng-model="var1" value="1"></input> 
<!-- another way, not approved per angular documentation outside of ngRepeat -->
<input ng-model="var2" ng-init="var2=2"></input>
</form>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  console.log("value of var1 is " + $scope.var1);
  console.log("value of var2 is " + $scope.var2);
  $scope.var1 = 3;
  $scope.var2 = 4;
}]);
```

[View this in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cuzetawete/2/edit?html,js,output)

Result:

```
value of var1 is undefined
value of var2 is undefined
[setting values to 3 and 4 displays fine in inputs]
```

So, it seems that the controller code is running before the input ng-model params are being evaluated. Which makes sense given that the controller is announced earlier than the input tags.

Question:

**is there any way to have the controller logic read and respect the initial value of var1 and var2?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mix Angular's `ng-model` and the regular HTML `value` attributes.

If you want to initialize your model, do it in your controller (or using `ng-init` but it is not recommended). And remove that `value` from your HTML.

```
$scope.var1 = 3;
$scope.var2 = 4;
```

Also, `ng-init` is evaluated after the controller is first read, so if you want to display the value from the `ng-init` you need to `$watch` for it: it will not be there the first time your controller is executed.

Comment: Hm, so if I want to initialize the model when the html and js are generated on the server side, i have to do that in the js somehow? like making a service that returns some pre-generated json?

Comment: could i put the value in a typical data- attribute, and read it using jquery/jqlite?

Comment: The whole idea of Angular is that you don't generate the HTML server side. You use the server to build your `model` (in the controller) and let the HTML renders accordingly to this model. This is for a better separation of concerns: the server only gives the information and has no concept of displaying.

Comment: @BenjaminWheeler Ok so I better understand your problem: if you want the initial value from the page generated by the server and somehow you don't want to use Ajax to do that, you could indeed put it in some `data` attribute or even keep that `value` and then read it to initialize your default model. That's a bit hacky though.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use Ajax, it's that I'm generating the page in a situation where the server knows which item to display, but the client doesn't. So client doesn't know which item to ask for, if server doesn't tell it. I guess the right thing to do would be to redo URL so that it is an actual Angular route and includes item id there?